# Where do values come from in nginx.conf.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm using Phusion Passenger with Rails (standalone) running on Heroku. The config file is passed in the Procfile settings.

I'd like to change the historical nginx.conf.erb file. I can easily add new values, but it isn't obvious to me where the variable values are coming from.

Examples from the file:

```
error_log '<%= @options[:log_file] %>' <% if @options[:log_level] >= LVL_DEBUG %>info<% end %>;
pid '<%= @options[:pid_file] %>';
```

or

```
<%= nginx_option :passenger_log_level, :log_level %>
```

or

```
<% for app in @apps %>
server {
    <% if app[:ssl] %>
        <% if app[:ssl_port] %>
            listen <%= nginx_listen_address(app) %>;
            listen <%= nginx_listen_address_with_ssl_port(app) %> ssl;
        <% else %>
            listen <%= nginx_listen_address(app) %> ssl;
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        listen <%= nginx_listen_address(app) %>;
    <% end %>
    server_name <%= app[:server_names].join(' ') %>;
```

So where are @options, @app coming from?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `nginx.conf.erb` for Passenger Standalone I assume you only care about the options that apply to Passenger and not nginx. All passenger options start with prefix `passenger_`, there are some unique options commonly used across many applications such as `pid_file`, `log_file`, etc. that apply to both passenger and nginx but for Standalone, they will only apply to Passenger.

These options are coming from when you start your passenger process with command line options: `bundle exec passenger start --log-level=3 --log-file=tmp.log`. If no values are provided, they will use their default values. For example, default values for PID file and Log file are listed when you start passenger.

```
$ bundle exec passenger start
======= Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started =======
PID file: /Users/phusion/myapp/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid   1
Log file: /Users/phusion/myapp/log/passenger.3000.log        2
Environment: development                     3
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/         4

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
===============================================================
```

There are various ways you can set these options such as through command line, in `Passengerfile.json`, or through environment variables.

A tip is that you can also set `binding.pry` in `nginx.conf.erb` and see what `@options` and `@apps` contains in debug mode.

```
# Add this as to the top of nginx.conf.erb

<% require 'pry' %>
<% binding.pry %>
```

You can view docs here:

[Starting a server](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/basics/ruby/passenger_command.html#starting-a-server)

[Command line options](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/basics/ruby/passenger_command.html#command-line-options)

[Passenger Standalone](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#introduction-to-configuring-passenger-standalone)

If you decide to use Passenger + Nginx, there will be additional options you care about such as @apps and values in @options that nginx itself requires and sets when it starts up. If using Passenger + Nginx, you'll only need to set two configuration options, `passenger_enabled` and `passenger_root`.

More details about Passenger + Nginx are in docs here:

[Passenger + Nginx](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/intro.html)

[Passenger + Nginx Configuration Reference](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#configuration-reference-for-passenger-+-nginx)